# Wildcard searches using dismax handler?

Tags: search, solr, wildcard, dismax, edismax

I have successfully indexed files, and want to be able to search using wildcards. I am currently using the dismaxRequestHandler (QueryType = dismax) for the searches so that I can search all the fields for the query.

A general search like 'computer' returns results but 'com*er' doesn't return any results.
Similary, a search like 'co?mput?r' returns no results.

Could someone please tell me a way to continue using dismax and be able to do wildcard searches in the 'q' field?
Does edismax handler have this? If so, How do I use it. I have Solr 1.4.1.

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Imran.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Grab latest (trunk) build from [Hudson](http://hudson.zones.apache.org/hudson/job/Solr-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/solr/dist/). Use `<str name="defType">edismax</str>` in the RequestHandler to activate edismax.

Comment: Thanks for you reponse.

Is the edismax handler available in the Solr 1.4.1 release ?

If yes, I did the exact same thing but its saying 'Unknown query type'. Any idea how to fix this?

If No, Do you know when it will be available as part of a stable release?

Comment: Thanks. Figured it out. Wildcard searches are working well now :)